# À quoi sert de distinguer la longueur des tirets ?

Tags: ponctuation, typographie

J'ignorais, en lisant des articles d'ailleurs contradictoires, ce que tout honnête homme sait distinguer :

1. le trait d'union d'un tiret, il n'y a rien de commun entre ces entités ;
2. qu'il y a plusieurs sortes de tirets :

   - le tiret-long ou cadratin ;
   - le tiret-moyen ou demi-cadratin ;
   - le tiret-court, qui, par exposé en abyme, comprend les variétés :

     - de césure ;
     - d'union insécable (le trait d'union n'est pas un tiret, mais le tiret court est dans certains cas un trait d'union ?) ; hélas le pharmacien refuse de me vendre de l'aspirine sans ordonnance ;
     - de quart-cadratin ;
     - d'union conditionnelle.

Pour simplifier, on admet d'assimiler "tiret" (tout court, mais non pas tiret-court) au signe moins.

**Questions:**

1. Quelle autorité a défini tout cela, quand ?
2. À quoi ça sert ? Améliorer la lisibilité, signifier une intention ?
3. Les éditeurs littéraires en usent-ils uniformément ?

Comment: Vaste question, un début de réponse : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthotypographie.

Comment: À l'avenir merci d'utiliser la partie [meta] pour ce qui concerne les pratiques en vigueur sur ce site, et de ne poser sur le site lui-même que des questions indépendantes de son fonctionnement. Un internaute qui découvre cette question en quête d'une réponse n'est a priori ni au courant ni intéressé par le fonctionnement du site. Il est aussi possible de discuter [chez Cosette](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette).

Comment: Si tu veux une réponse à la question qui est dans le titre tu devrais tenter ta chance sur [graphicdesign.se]. Seule la sous-question sur une éventuelle autorité a un rapport direct avec le français.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, l'orthotypographie est quelque chose à la frontière entre la langue et la typographie, elle ne me gène pas sur le site (mais je ne sais pas si la question porte sur l'usage orthotypographique ou, ce que le ton et l'introduction peuvent laisser croire, sur les usages de fr.se relatifs à l'orthotypographie, auquel cas elle est à déplacer sur meta)

Comment: @Unfrancophone: tout à fait, ce n'etait qu'un conseil, il me semble qu'ils savent répondre à ces questions-là sur Graphic Design.

Comment: Une référence (**LA** référence ?) est le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale*, ouvrage réédité régulièrement depuis de nombreuses années de façon à suivre évolution de la PAO. La généralisation de la PAO a généralisé des règles d'usage qui ne s'imposaient pas quand la majorité de la population écrivait « à la main ». Ceci n'est pas spécifique au français, l'anglais a le *Chicago Manual of Style*, je suppose que chaque langue a ses références.

Comment: @Laure, si j'ai bonne mémoire, ce lexique fait mal la différence entre les règles d'usage quasiment universel en français (ou du moins en France, les typographes suisses ont édité leur propre marche, et les usages québécois sont parfois aussi différent) et celles plus particulières à l'IN.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Bien sûr, mais ce code est majoritairement suivi en France, par exemple par Wikidpedia : « Les règles typographiques  du *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l’Imprimerie nationale* (LRTUIN) : « Séduire le lecteur et faciliter la lecture résument les qualités d’une bonne typographie ».  » ou recommandé, par exemple sur  http://www.orthotypographie.fr/.

Comment: @Unfrancophone La typographie est effectivement nationale. Il s'agit non pas de règles mais de conventions qui sont à ce titre suivies ou non (d'où je pense l'absence de disctinction : on normalise des habitudes pour l'IN). On constate que les règles changent selon les supports (les journaux ont tendance à supprimer des espaces qui leurs semblent superflus) et les pays (jouez avec les langues et pays dans un traitement de texte pour voir les différences de correction automatique). Je me réfère souvent aux règles de Wikipédia dans la mesure où elles sont en majeure partie tirées du Lexique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pourquoi les plus prestigieux éditeurs littéraires n'en usent-ils pas uniformément ?

Les réponses se trouvent dans cette question. L'usage des tirets est dictée par la typographie, par la lisibilité, l'esthétique, le visuel : c'est le travail de l'éditeur. Or tous ne sont pas d'accord sur ce qui est efficace ou plaisant visuellement, tous n'ont pas la même sensibilité ni les mêmes standards.

C'est donc l'usage, celui des typographes, au nom de la lisibilité et de l'esthétique, qui dicte cela.

Comment: Bravo, vous avez très bien compris ce que je voulais dire. Il est heureux que le choix de la police de caractères ne soit pas (encore ?) imposé par les censeurs.

Comment: Pourriez-vous expliciter votre phrase où se trouve `le efficace` côte à côte ? Pourquoi aucune élision ici ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Ça ressemble à une faute de frappe. _"ce qui est efficace ou plaisant"_.

Answer (score 10):

La typographie est souvent plus dictée par l'histoire et l'esthétique que par la logique. Néanmoins, il y a des raisons de distinguer ces signes.

Le [trait d'union](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_d%27union) (*hyphen*, le plus court, celui des mots composés comme *abat-jour* et *week-ends*) a une raison objective d'être court : c'est un séparateur de mots qui est moins fort qu'une espace, il est donc logique qu'il soit plus court qu'une espace, où au moins pas beaucoup plus long (l'espace est de largeur variable pour la justification des lignes).

Le [tiret demi-cadratin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret#Tiret_moyen) est relativement peu connu. Il sert de séparation entre les mots plus forte qu'une espace, il est donc logique qu'il soit plus long qu'une espace. Par exemple, la station de métro parisienne [Saint-Denis–Université](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Denis_-_Universit%C3%A9_(m%C3%A9tro_de_Paris)) est située près de l'université de la commune de Saint-Denis : la partie « Saint-Denis » forme un tout, il faut donc une séparation plus forte entre *Denis* et *Université* qu'entre *Saint* et *Denis*. À l'heure où j'écris, Wikipédia et le site web de la RATP (société qui gère le métro à Paris) ne font pas la différence ; par contre, sur les [plans](http://www.ratp.fr/informer/pdf/orienter/f_plan.php?fm=pdf&nompdf=metro&loc=reseaux) officiels soignés, on voit nettement la différence de longueur des tirets.

Le [tiret cadratin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret#Tiret_long) est une ponctuation relativement forte — plus qu'une virgule, ambiguë par rapport à un point-virgule ou aux deux-points, et moins qu'une ponctuation de fin de phrase. Il est donc logique qu'elle soit plus longue qu'un simple trait d'union. Bien sûr, la logique a ses limites : le point est le moins visible des signes de ponctuation alors que c'est une ponctuation forte.

Le signe moins n'est pas situé sur la même échelle car il appartient aux polices mathématiques, qui ne sont souvent pas les mêmes que pour le corps du texte. Bien que le signe moins et le trait d'union partagent le même caractère dans Unicode, ils n'ont donc en pratique pas la même apparence. Le signe moins a la même largeur et la même graisseur que le signe plus, il est souvent plus épais que les tirets ou le trait d'union dans un même texte, et quasiment toujours nettement plus long qu'un trait d'union.

Comment: Le tiret demi-cadratin (“en dash”) s’emploie aussi entre des dates ou d’autres nombres, par exemple: 1914–1948, 6–8 h.